# Optimization through machine learning

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

I've got a system that takes 15 points out of a 17 by 17 grid as input (order doesn't matter), and generates a single scalar as output. The system is not representable by a formal function.

The goal is to find the optimal 15 points so that the output scalar is minimum. Solving this problem exhaustively simply takes too much time to be practical as each run takes 14 seconds.

I've started taking a machine learning course online. But this problem does seem to be rather unsophisticated and I wonder if anyone can point me to the right direction. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This problem is very underspecified. You want to minimize a function. Differentiable function? Convex function? Real-valued inputs? Boolean inputs? Integer inputs?

Comment: The system is a black box to me for all practical purposes, not something representable by a formal function.
The input are those 15 pairs of coordinates out of the 17X17 grid.

Comment: The task "Minimize a function f: {1,..,17}^2 -> {some ordered set}" is *not* underspecified imo -- just assume as little as possible. Still I agree that providing as much information as possible is always useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing). I guess this will be close to optimal here.

Therefore, start with a random distribution of the 15 points. Then, in each iteration change one and accept the new state if the resulting scalar value is lower. If it is larger, accept with a certain probability (a Boltzmann factor). Eventually you have to try this for a small number of randomly chosen initial states and afterwards accept the lowest value.

Comment: Thanks. I'll read about it and give it a try. I did forget to mention that there is a standard set of 15 points to begin with according to past experience, only many of them ended up deviating by quite a lot.

Comment: Alright, did some reading and I think I know how to implement this. One question though, shouldn't I change all 15 points at once for each iteration?

Comment: That depends, but I wouldn't change all particles at once, because then the steps might be rejected often. I would start by changing a single point, but keep this number `n` variable in the implementation. Intuitively, I would expect `n=1` to `4` to work well. But anyway, you will get a much much faster optimization than by your exhaustive search (which corresponds to checking approximately 4*10^24 states!)